# Перенос вопросов с Меты

Tags: поддержка, мета, перенос-вопросов

При закрытии вопроса на основном сайте есть пункт для переноса его на Мету:

> [image: на мету]

На самой же Мете подобного пункта для переноса на основной сайт нет. Почему?

А то тут как раз [возникла такая необходимость](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5130/176217).

Comment: У модераторов на этом диалоге есть выбиралка для любого сайта из сети. Если надо - оставляйте тревоги.

Comment: @PashaPash тревоги на Мете слишком долго висят в ожидании. Наверное из-за задержек с з/п :)